# How to add different filter comparators for different columns in angular ng-table?

Tags: angularjs, filter, ngtable

I have created a table using ng-table as below.

```
 $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
   filterOptions: { filterComparator:angular.equals },
   dataset:$scope.usersList  
          });
```

This my html.

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td data-title="'User ID'" header-class="'text-left'" sortable="'id'" filter="{ 'id': 'text' }">
            {{user.id}}
        </td>

        <td data-title="'Username'" header-class="'text-left'" sortable="'username'" filter="{ 'username': 'text' }">
            {{user.username}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Name'" filter="{status: 'select'}" filter-data="status" sortable="'status'">{{ user.status }}</td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

When filter "status", I want to get the output as exact match. But when filter "username" I want it to be as contains. Since I have given "filterComparator" as "angular.equals " ,now the whole table is filtered as exact match. But how can I filter only "status" column as exact match and others as contains?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it can be done in a clean way.

For the same use case, I wrote a single `filterComparator` function, and decided the kind of comparison I wanted to do on the basis of the type of the parameters passed to the function.

```
function filterComparator(actual, expected) {
    if (expected instanceof Date) {
        // using moment.js for date comparison
        return moment(actual).isSame(moment(expected), 'day');
    } else {
        // default: case insensitive substring match
        return actual.toString().search(new RegExp(expected.toString(), 'i')) != -1;
    }
}
```

Have you been able to solve the problem in a different way? I would be interested to hear.

Comment: @spc91 thanks. My solution may indeed have issues if you want to filter in a different way data that has the same type (e.g. two string columns that have to be filtered with different criteria).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a filter function to compare equality of two strings

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('equalComparator', function($filter) {
    return function(values, searchTerm , property) {
        var filtered = [];

        if(typeof values != 'undefined' && typeof searchTerm != 'undefined') {
            angular.forEach(values, function(value) {

                if(value[property] == searchTerm ) {
                    filtered.push(value);
                }

            });
        }

        return filtered;
    }
})
```

And then used this "equalComparator" in ngtable filter method as below

```
   if(params.filter()[//column name to filter]) {
          $scope.filteredData = $filter('equalComparator')($scope.filteredData,params.filter()[//column name to filter] ,//field name to filter);
    }
```